# random number C++

Tags: c++

Sorry about that. My question is I'm trying to generate a random number with an input of 4 or 55 . Using srand() ranging from 0 t0 9

here is my code so far:

```
using namespace std;

int main() {
   int seedVal = 0;

  srand(seedVal); 

   seedVal= time(0);



   cout << (rand () % 9) + 1 << endl;
   cout << (rand () % 9) + 1 << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems you forgot to include a question in your question.

Comment: `srand(seedVal); 

   seedVal= time(0);` what is that?

Comment: I'm trying to generate a random number, seedVal would be my variable. When I run my code and the input is 4 for seedVal my expected out put should be 1 and 3. But it keeps giving me random numbers.

Comment: Sorry about that. My question is I'm trying to generate a random number with an input of 4 or 55 . Using srand() ranging from 0 t0 9.

Comment: Why are you changing the `seedVal` after it will no longer be used? Put `seedVal= time(0);` before `srand(seedVal);` you want a seed that will change.

Comment: You should edit the question rather than posting a comment. Then *maybe* it'll get re-opened.

Comment: @Sori That's still not a question.

Comment: Your question is still very confusing. I am not sure if you want it to randomly print 4 or 55 (which a single rand() % 2 could be used with an array containing the 2 values) or do something else. Either way it is unanswerable in its current form because we can not guess what you actually want.

Answer (score 2):

*Don't* use `srand` and `rand`. `rand` has a very low period, is usually based on a linear congruential generator (very bad random properties) and *don't* use modulo (`%`) to get a range of numbers - you are introducing bias. Use the facillities in [the random header](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) instead.
In this case you probably want `std::random_device` (for the seed), `std::mt19937` (for the generator) and `std::uniform_int_distribution` (for the distribution).

Btw, you are *always* seeding with a value of `0` (zero).

Comment: Currious as to the reason for the downvote??

Comment: not me, but i could imagine that it is for answering a non-question

Comment: You may be right. But the answer *does* contain everything OP needs to solve his problem (IMHO). Besides, he *did* edit the question to include a (somewhat) question..

Comment: Upvote (+1) for not just pointing out the error, but pointing out the betterness of `<random>`

Comment: I've figured it out Thanks!

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>   // Enables use of rand()
#include <ctime>     // Enables use of time()
using namespace std;

int main() {
   int seedVal = 0;
   
   srand(seedVal);
   cout << (rand() % 10) << endl;
   cout << (rand() % 10) << endl;
   return 0;
}

Comment: @Sori you probably just want to delete this question. It will provide no help  at all to a future reader.

Comment: You may have figured out how to include a few headers to enable you to use `rand`. But you have *not* figured out that the *real* solution is to *not use `rand`* in the first place. Talk about solving the wrong problem...